# SQL HAVING clause with aggregate fuctions?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to find the employees of company that have salary bigger than the average salary of all the employees. I would like to point out from the start that I don't want the average salary to be present in the final result, so I ommit it in the SELECT statement. These are the things I've tried:

```
SELECT employee.lastname,employee.firstname,employee.salary FROM employee
GROUP BY employee.salary
HAVING employee.salary > avg(employee.salary);
```

**This results in an empty result table**

However the following surprisingly returns all the employees of the company despite the '=' symbol.

```
SELECT employee.lastname,employee.firstname,employee.salary FROM employee
GROUP BY employee.salary
HAVING employee.salary = avg(employee.salary);
```

This returns empty table again:

```
SELECT employee.lastname,employee.firstname,employee.salary FROM employee
WHERE (SELECT avg(employee.salary) FROM employee 
GROUP BY employee.salary
HAVING employee.salary > AVG(employee.salary));
```

So to conclude this post I would appreciate some insight about the right use of HAVING with an aggregate function, some insight about the reason that the snippets result in an empty table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `GROUP BY employee.salary` then the average salary of each group is equal to `employee.salary` because all the salaries of the group are equal.
So the condition:

```
employee.salary > avg(employee.salary)
```

is always `FALSE` and you get no rows,
and the condition:

```
employee.salary = avg(employee.salary)
```

is always `TRUE` and the result is to get all the groups returned.
 
The correct code to get what you want is:

```
SELECT employee.lastname, employee.firstname, employee.salary 
FROM employee
WHERE employee.salary > (SELECT avg(employee.salary) FROM employee);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems i was pretty confused with the GROUP BY statement :)

Comment: Group by lets you club a particular columns data into groups thats the reason you have `having` used with group by because it filters within those groups unlinke `where` which filters the whole tables data

Answer (score 1):

Remove the starting open bracket `(` before `avg(..` and last closing bracket `)`  before the semicolon as you have misplaced the brackets leading to syntax error

```
    SELECT  employee.lastname,
  employee.firstname,employee.salary 
   FROM employee
   WHERE employee.salary > 
( SELECT avg(employee.salary) FROM 
   employee);
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the mistake, it worked. However i edited the question removing the part about the syntax error so that it reflects a question  that can help future users ( the reason that the queries return a blank table) and i accepted the answer of the other person since they answered the above question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT lastname, firstname, salary
FROM employee
WHERE salary > (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM employee)
ORDER BY salary DESC
```

The sub-query for the average doesn't need a `GROUP BY` when only an aggregate function is used in the `SELECT` or `HAVING` clause.

Or to use something more fancy:

```
SELECT lastname, firstname, salary
FROM
(
    SELECT lastname, firstname, salary
    , AVG(salary) OVER () AS avg_salary
    FROM employee
) q
WHERE salary > avg_salary
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with two sets/tables, one record-level and the other aggregated, even if they're the same set:

```
select e.lastname , e.firstname , e.salary 
FROM employee e, (
    select avg(a.salary) avg_salary
    from employee a
) av
where 1=1
  and e.salary > av.avg_salary
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have aggregated by `employee.salary`.  So, in this query:

```
HAVING employee.salary > avg(employee.salary);
```

Each row *before* the `HAVING` has exactly one `salary` value.  The average of a single value -- no matter how many are in the group -- is that value.  Because a value cannot be bigger than itself, no rows are returned.

This clause:

```
 HAVING employee.salary = avg(employee.salary);
```

is exactly the same thing, except all rows with non-`NULL` salaries match this condition.  Hence, all rows are returned.

As others have mentioned, the more typical solution is a subquery:

```
select e.*
from employee e
where e.salary > (select avg(e2.salary) from employee e2);
```

Note the use of table aliases.  These are highly recommended.

A more modern solution would use window functions:

```
select . . .   -- select the columns you want
from (select e.*, avg(e.salary) over () as avg_salary
      from employee e
     ) e
where e.salary > avg_salary;
```

Comment: *Note the use of table aliases. These are highly recommended.* not in the query you use them. They are not needed at all and only add noise to the code.